# How can I reference a global variable from within a function?

Tags: python, global, var, python-3.4

Hi I'm a beginner programmer. I don't know how can I call a variable from function.
I have two def `calcular()` and `guardar()`. I get some variables from `calcular()` that I will call later, but when I call variables in `guardar()`, it tells me that `variable is not defined`. I tried making `global var`, but it doesn't work. Hope you can help me

This is a little of my code...

```
def calcular():

    if nClient == "":
        texto = ("Inserta Numero de cliente")
        ventanaMensaje(texto)
    else:
        if cl1=="":
            texto = ("Inserta Clave")
            ventanaMensaje(texto)       
        else:
            if aB1 == "":
                texto = ("Inserta Cantidad")
                ventanaMensaje(texto)
            else:
                try:
                    clt = open("preciosEsp.txt","r+")
                    lClt = clt.readlines()
                    rClt = lClt[0]
                    sClt = rClt.split("'")
                    nRClt = sClt[0]

                    if nClient == nRClt:
                        cReg=sClt[1]

                        if cl1== cReg:
                                prc=sClt[2]
                         else:
                            k=1
                            while cl1 != cReg:
                                cReg=sClt[k]
                                k=k+2
                                if cl1== cReg:
                                    ñ=k-1
                                    prc=sClt[ñ]
                    else:
                       x = 0
                        while nClient != nRClt:
                            rClt = lClt[x]
                            sClt = rClt.split("'")
                            nRClt = sClt[0]
                            x=x+1
                            if nClient == nRClt:
                                cReg=sClt[1]
                                if cl1==cReg:
                                    prc=sClt[2]
                                else:
                                    k=1
                                    while cl1 != cReg:
                                        cReg=sClt[k]
                                        k=k+2
                                        if cl1== cReg:
                                            ñ=k-1
                                            prc=sClt[ñ]

                    indice=int(prc)+3

                    pdcts = open("productos.txt","r+")
                    lPdcts = pdcts.readlines()
                    rPdcts = lPdcts[0]
                    sPdcts= rPdcts.split("'")
                    nPdcts = sPdcts[0]
                    t = 0
                    if cl1 == nPdcts:
                        precio1=sPdcts[indice]
                        global txtD1################## MAKE A GLOBAL VAR 
                        txtD1=sPdcts[1]  #### THIS IS THE VARIABLE ########
def guardar():

    guardarDatos = (n+txtD1)  ################# I CALL HERE, BUT TELL ME THAT VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED
```

Answer (score 3):

If you really want a global variable, you'd define it outside of any function

```
txtD1 = None
def calcular():
    ...
```

it will then exist at module level.  However, globals are rarely (read: never) the solution you should be using, instead you should be `return`ing information from functions rather than modifying global state.  You'd then pass that information into another function to use.

The `global` keyword in python says that you are referencing a global variable, not creating a new one.  However, in your code no such name exists, so you're not actually referencing anything.

Answer (score 1):

first create your "database" somewhere global

```
clt = dict(map(lambda x:x.split(" ",1),open("preciosEsp.txt","r+"))
```

now you can acess it anywhere with

```
clt.get(nClient)
```

next calcular should return the values you want

```
def calcular():
    ...
    precio = clt.get(nClient)
    return [precio,nClient,...]
```

then you would store the returned values (or do something with them as soon as they are returned )